# Waiting for server.. UR5 arm

Tags: ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I'm trying to do is getting the UR5 talking to ROS, i experience a problem with executing the node test_move.py after bringing up the UR5 and had no trouble with that using this command

roslaunch ur_bringup ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.168.1.200 [reverse_port:=50001]
and also got a message saying " Robot connected"

But trying to run the node test_move.py in a different window , it only showes "waiting for server..." and it never execute it.

I'm using Indigo and firmware version 1.8. Any idea on how can i fix this problem?

Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229351/waiting-for-server..-ur5-arm/) by [Baker Salama](https://answers.ros.org/users/25752/baker-salama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxgitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/30480/maxgitt/) on 2017-08-04**:
How do I know which firmware version I am using? I am trying to figure out if the modern driver is right for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem by downloading the package ur_modern_driver from
https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver instead of the package from Universal Robots (ur_driver)

---

Originally posted by [Baker Salama](https://answers.ros.org/users/25752/baker-salama/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0